# Incomplete Timestamp using ADODB with VBA for Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I am trying to pull some data from SQL Server to Microsoft Excel 2007.  I have the connection setup and everything seems to be working fine except for the Timestamps.  I can only get the dates to come through, not the corresponding hours, minutes or seconds.  I can pull data from the SQL database using the Excel ODBC query tool and the hours and minutes are listed there.  I have tried a variety of different CAST() options.  None of them have solved my problem.  I am running Windows XP.  I don't know what version of Microsoft SQL is running on the server.  My code is shown below.

```
 Sub Populate_Sheet(theSheet As Worksheet)

    'Declare variables'
        Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

        Dim executeThisSQLStatement As String
        'Dim target As Worksheet
        'Set target = theSheet

        executeThisSQLStatement = "SELECT CAST(DateHour_CPT AS TIMESTAMP) FROM EnergyData_v"

    'Open Connection'
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQLServer};Data Source=DataMart;User ID=acctname.value;Password=mypass.value;"

        objMyConn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = executeThisSQLStatement
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    'Open Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
        objMyRecordset.Open

    'Copy Data to Excel'
        theSheet.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to cast as DATETIME and not TIMESTAMP? SQL Server made a big mistake when they named the TIMESTAMP type - while it *sounds* like the ANSI SQL type that represents something to do with date and time, it has nothing to do with either. Try this in a query window, ignoring all of this VBA and Excel interference: `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Also, you should never have to say "I don't know which version I'm running" - this is trivial to obtain using `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: Its probably an issue with Excel formatting. Try to change the format of the date column cells to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Comment: I tried both DATETIME and TIMESTAMP.  DATETIME would return the dates but not the hh:mm.  TIMESTAMP would not return anything.  I also tried all of the formatting options for the cells in Excel.  The time is coming through as 00:00:00.000 for all of the database entries.  I will get the SQL Server verision tomorrow morning using that Select statement.  This timestamp issue has really gotten under my skin.  I sank so much time into figuring this out today.  I can't turn back now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick, I think I have found a solution for you :)
Let me demonstrate using my sample data.

By default, Excel does not have a `DateTime` cell format. This means it cannot store a date and time within one cell. When it comes to data presentation it seems that Excel attempts to use just the most recognizable format - which is date. It still stores the time but formats cells to a date format losing/*dropping* the time. 

 Take a look at the below screenshot:
[image: sample]

As you can see the data displayed in cell looks just like a normal date. But if you look at the formula bar - the time exists but its not being displayed.

At the end of your code, I have added a `Debug.Print` line :
`Debug.print Range("B6").Value & vbCrlf & Range("B6").Value2`

the results I have got
`25/06/2013 16:00:27` 
`41450.6669791667`
Therefore, I have conformed that ***what you are seeing in a cell in Excel isn't exactly what its being referred to***

---

The next step was to write a function that would iterate over the cells and change the formatting and what's being seen. 
To achieve both: `date` and `time` in one cell I decided to format the cell as `Text`.

```
Private Sub FormatDateAndTime(ByRef sheet As Worksheet, start As Long, column As String)
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range
    For i = start To sheet.Range(column & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = sheet.Range(column & i)
        Dim str As String
        str = Split(rng.Value, " ")(0) & " " & Split(rng.Value, " ")(1)
        rng.NumberFormat = "@"
        rng = str
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

The `FormatDateAndTime()` function takes 3 parameters: 
- active sheet
- starting row
- column with the dates
To call the function add this line right before the `End Sub` in your code

```
  // Copy Data to Excel
        theSheet.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

  // this is the line you want to add
    FormatDateAndTime sheet:=theSheet, start:=6, column:="A"

End Sub
```

**note:** *I have send other parameters in my sample to demontrate results but the above is going to work in your case*

Ok, after running the code You should get the results as follows 
**note:** *I ran this only for column `B` in my sample to show the difference.*

[image: results1]

**note:** I ran this one for both columns `B` and `C` 
[image: results2]

---

Your complete solution:

```
Sub Populate_Sheet(theSheet As Worksheet)

'Declare variables'
    Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim executeThisSQLStatement As String
    'Dim target As Worksheet
    'Set target = theSheet

    executeThisSQLStatement = "SELECT CAST(DateHour_CPT AS TIMESTAMP) FROM EnergyData_v"

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQLServer};Data Source=DataMart;User ID=acctname.value;Password=mypass.value;"

    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyCmd.CommandText = executeThisSQLStatement
    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.Open

'Copy Data to Excel'
    Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

    FormatDateAndTime sheet:=theSheet, start:=6, column:="A"
End Sub

Private Sub FormatDateAndTime(ByRef sheet As Worksheet, start As Long, column As String)
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range
    For i = start To sheet.Range(column & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = sheet.Range(column & i)
        Dim str As String
        str = Split(rng.Value, " ")(0) & " " & Split(rng.Value, " ")(1)
        rng.NumberFormat = "@"
        rng = str
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

If this answer has helped you, please accept and/or upvote it! :) Thanks and good luck

Comment: I copied your code and it worked perfectly on the first try.  Thank you so much.  This has really helped me out a lot!  I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation but this is exactly what I needed.